# Why Servlet program outputting HTML text as it is?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I created one program that prints 'Welcome to our site' text on browser using servlet. It works fine inside the eclipse default browser but when I use that URL to other browser it displays text as below:

[image]

And below is the image of the code that is working well inside eclipse browser
[image]

**And my code is as follows:**

```
public class WelcomePage extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {

}
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.println("<h3>Welcome to our site<h3>");
    out.println("<form>");
    out.println("</form>");
}
@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

Comment: Try setting content type of response to `text/html`.

Comment: how to set content type? and what it means?

Comment: Before you create writer invoke `res.setContentType("text/html");` also take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Yeah in any webpage you must tell it what content is going to be there, just like if you put javascript you do the script tag and tell it what type of script it's going to be

Answer (score 1):

After adding res.setContentType(text/html); problem resolved :)

Before sending data to client (displayed by Browser on client machine), the Servlet container informs the client browser of what type of data is being sent now. The data that can be sent may be simple plain text, html form, xml form, image form of type gif or jpg, excel sheet etc. To send this information, the Servlet container uses response object with the method setContentType().

**Some examples :**

```
response.setContentType("text/html");           
response.setContentType("text/plain");  
response.setContentType("text/css");            
response.setContentType("application/html");
response.setContentType("image/gif");
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: It should be noted that when you send content to somewhere else, you should inform in the header or somewhere else previously agreed upon. For instance, text/html states that is "text", as each byte represents a characther in that browser encode... and that html means that the text must be read and "html content" processed (mostly tags, like </br>, <h> etc.)..... Further types tell what is expected to be done with the inputted information. Never transfer Json, and tell its zip, or the receiver will make unexpected mistakes with the result.